# asp.net : How to check if a dynamically created control has posted back 

Tags: asp.net

how to check if a dynamically created control has posted back?The below code is not working.

```
Control control = null;

    string ctrlname = page.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTTARGET");
    if (ctrlname != null && ctrlname != string.Empty)
    {
        control = page.FindControl(ctrlname);
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string ctl in page.Request.Form)
        {
            Control c = page.FindControl(ctl);
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
            if (c is System.Web.UI.WebControls.ImageButton)
            {
                control = c;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return control;
```

I have created some imagebuttons dyanmically on page_Init. But the above code always returns null. Why is that? How can I check If an image button has posted back?

Note: I am able to handle the click events of those imagebuttons.

Comment: I'm not following you. What do you mean "check if an image button has posted back"? The click events you are handling are the post-backs, no?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which control has initiated the postback at Page_Load time, one [Steve C. Orr](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t90304-detect-which-imagebutton-caused-postback.html) has some tips:

> You can override the
>   RaisePostBackEvent method of the Page
>   class. The first parameter sent to
>   this method is the object that caused
>   the postback. Remember to call
>   `base.RaisePostBackEvent()` so the
>   postback event gets raised correctly.
>
> Alternately, instead of the load event
>   you could move your conditional code
>   to the PreRender event , which happens
>   after all the control events. So by
>   then you'll know which control(s)
>   caused the postback.

...

> If your ImageButton is inside a grid,
>   you can put on your button an
>   commandName and on itemCommand check
>   if the command is your command.

http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t90304-detect-which-imagebutton-caused-postback.html

Comment: What if I need the control's ID in `Page_Load` itself; not `RaisePostBackEvent` ?